# Using auto in CSS calc

Tags: css

I searched a lot but I didn't find a good resource.

I want to calculate a div height as its contents plus a fix size. I tested `calc(auto+50px)` but unfortunately It doesn't work (the browser does not interpret it as valid code).

Comment: You can't use `auto` in `calc()`. But why not just use `padding-bottom` instead?

Comment: are you open to jQuery solutions?

Comment: no i can't use java script

Comment: Just in case you want to ever reference browser compatibility: http://caniuse.com/#search=calc

Comment: thank you all.Evan idea was worked for me like a charm.I accepted the rink answer that has the same idea.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Does this produce the desired result?

```
div {
    height: auto;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to go less than auto, like `calc(auto - 50px)`?